# Rate increase analysis, way to to calculate

Tags: statistics

Story that I need to go over auditors' note to provide feedback for all Provisions where Increase/Decrease > 20% line in Column **H**. Looking into provided doc I don't get how they calculate this e.g.              `= 1 - (RateOld / RateNew)`
There nothing special behind those Rates, higher rate is better, and indicates better participation.
I need to be very careful before jumping into conclusion, don't want to mess with auditor's way.  Anybody knows what is the logic/science/approach behind his formula,  I pasted on the right more traditional ones  I used.

Best
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, assume that they just switched new and old columns in provided sheet, so we divide by New Rate rather then Old.  those formulas are same, first one always positive:

`1-(G/D) = (D-G)/D`

And logically this answers question how much change was last year, rather then This year.